# How to get the max row number in the Partition over by SQL Syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have duplicate file name record in the file name column on various dates. I need to pick the Max - Rownumber of filename and its corresponding date.

```
with cte as
(
select [FileName], ProcessDate,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by [FileName]) RowNumber 
from  StagingTable    
)
select * from cte 
order by rownumber desc
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i need max row number..  each file name can be on maximum number of times

Comment: `select * from cte where rownumber = 1` ?

Comment: Change your `partition by` clause to `order by processdate desc`, then add where `rownumber = 1` to your query...

Comment: I need to pick the max row number. Having "Order by  desc " will only help in the date. but i need the total number of duplicate take place ..

Comment: Post some sample data and expected output

Comment: 'i need the total number of duplicate take place' - why do you use numbering, why not COUNT?

Comment: By the way, you have actually answered your own question: per Filename, you would need the MAX row number in the outer query.

Comment: You need to `order by` some other field than `filename`.  If not, you will not be able to guarantee the order of the results (the `row_number` can change arbitrarily).  So saying you want the `max` doesn't make sense unless you have a `max` to `order by` (hence `processdate desc`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not addressing your question but I think this is what you want. This will give you the last ProcessDate with one SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    [FileName]
    ,MAX (ProcessDate) AS LastProcessDate
    ,COUNT (*) FileNameOccurence
FROM StagingTable
GROUP BY [FileName]
```

If so, don't make it more complicated with nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
select [FileName], ProcessDate,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by [FileName] desc) RowNumber 
from  StagingTable    
)
select * from cte 
where RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: this query will not give the maximum row number.

Comment: well, if you need opposite order, just order by desc. edited.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want the latest file where there are more than one with the same file name - You don't necessarily need a CTE - a subquery would work just fine

```
 select *
 from(
 select [FileName], ProcessDate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by 
 ProcessDate desc) RN 
 from  StagingTable
 )files
 where RN = 1
```